# Аналог SonarQube для отображения результатов

Tags: sonarqube

Добрый день. Есть своя система для расчета checkstyle и cpd. Можно ли как-то импортировать эти данные в SonarQube или какую-то аналогичную систему. Не для анализа, а просто выводить результаты?

Comment: Расшифруйте пожалуйста cpd.

Comment: copy-paste detector